# Move one row up to the top in Propel with join

Tags: php, mysql, sql, propel

I have such query

```
$packages = PackageQuery::create()
            ->joinPackageHasTable()
            ->addAscendingOrderByColumn(' CASE name
                  WHEN package.package_id=3 THEN 0
                  ELSE - 1
               END')
            ->groupByName()
            ->find();
```

What I try to achieve is to keep this query and forward row with id equal 3 up to the top.
This query doesn't work and returns

> Criteria:(Error: Cannot fetch TableMap for undefined table: CASE name
>   WHEN package.)

table package exists both in database and schema

Comment: Remove `name`.  Your condition appears to be on `package_id`.

Comment: Same error, as if table was not found

Comment: Was my answer below of any use to you? =)

Answer (score 0):

You can not order in this way using propel. You first have to select whatever you want to order by with an alias, and then you can order it. addAscendingOrderByColumn will check if the requested column is known by propel, and custom sql is not recognised.

---

For example, in my own project I use the following code:

```
        $query->withColumn(
            'ISNULL(' . BlaBlaTableMap::COL_MIN_LEFT . ')',
            'not_unlimited'
        );
        $query->orderBy('not_unlimited');
```

In your case, I think something like this would work:

```
        $packages = PackageQuery::create()
            ->withColumn(
                sprintf(
                    'CASE WHEN %s = 3 THEN -1 ELSE 0 END',
                    PackageHasTableTableMap::COL_PACKAGE_ID
                ),
                'is_not_three'
            )
            ->orderBy('is_not_three')
            ->usePackageHasTableQuery()
            ->endUse()
            ->groupByName()
            ->find();
```